# What to do with a village too close to my Iron Farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have made an iron farm and I read something about villages having to be 150 blocks from the iron farm for it to function efficiently. I only read this after building it though, and there's a village about 120 blocks from the edge of the farm, and I cannot be asked to rebuild it.
I instead thought: could it be possible to get rid of the village? (I destroyed all the beds, workstations, doors, bells, houses and everything I could see that was village related).
Do I also need to kill all villagers becuase I created a few new ones to breed?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the reason that you can't have a village too close to an iron farm is because villagers will only spawn an iron golem if they haven't seen another iron golem recently. Villiger spawn iron golems periodically, so having a village near an iron farm means there is a risk that an iron golem from the village will wonder too close to the farm and prevent more iron golems from spawning.

Villagers also won't spawn an iron golem if they haven't slept recently. *(I'm not sure if this is true for villagers running away from mobs, as their behaviour changes to make it easier for them to spawn iron golems. This is why the iron farm works.)*

Because of this, I'd imagine that destroying most of the beds would be enough, however you could kill most of the villagers as well if you want to be safe.

See https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Iron_golem_summoning

I think it should be ok to leave up to two villagers. *(or 4 if you are sure that aggressive mobs will not be able to go near them)*

I'm sorry that I've not been able to provide a concrete answer, however I hope my information is somewhat helpful.

Comment: Thank you i will try to spawn proof the area so no aggresice mobs will be able to spawn